# Objective-C - weak property - getter autoreleases (Automatic Reference Counting)

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, getter, autorelease, weak-references

I have a doubt regarding `weak` property in ARC (auto reference counting)

**My understanding (correct me if I am wrong):**

`weak` property behaves similar to the `assign` property except that when the instance that the property was pointing to gets destroyed, the ivar is made to point to nil.

**Question:**

1. I just feel that the getter of the `weak` property retains and autoreleases. Isn't it suppose to behave like getter of the `assign` property where the getter doesn't retain and autorelease ?(pls refer to the program)

**Program:**

I have given below the program with the actual output and my expected output.

**Note** - *When I change property from `weak` to `assign` my expected output is met*

```
#import<Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface A : NSObject
- (void) dealloc;
@end

@implementation A
- (void) dealloc
{
    printf("\tinstance of A deallocated = %p\n", self);
}
@end

@interface B : NSObject
@property (weak) A* xa1;
- (void) dealloc;
@end

@implementation B
@synthesize xa1;
- (void) dealloc
{
    printf("\tinstance of B deallocated = %p\n", self);
}
@end


int main()
{
    B* b1 = [[B alloc] init];

    @autoreleasepool                        //autoreleasepool 1
    {   
        {                                   //block 1
            A* a1 = [[A alloc] init];
            printf("\ta1 = %p\n", a1);

            b1.xa1 = a1; 

            A* a3 = b1.xa1;

            printf("--- end of block 1\n");
        }                                       //at this point i expected instance pointed by a1 to be destroyed

        printf("--- end of autoreleasepool 1\n");
    }   

    printf("---- end of main\n");

    return(0);
}
```

**Actual Output:**

```
    a1 = 0x10d713f50
--- end of block 1
--- end of autoreleasepool 1
    instance of A deallocated = 0x10d713f50
---- end of main
    instance of B deallocated = 0x10d713d30
```

**My Expected Output:**

```
    a1 = 0x10d713f50
--- end of block 1
    instance of A deallocated = 0x10d713f50
--- end of autoreleasepool 1
---- end of main
    instance of B deallocated = 0x10d713d30
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supplying `weak` on a property assumes `__weak` ownership for the ivar, i.e. it's just an instruction for `@synthesize`.

According to http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html §4.2, reading `__weak` variable requires retaining the object (and releasing after, of course):

> Reading occurs when performing a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on an object lvalue.
>
> - For __weak objects, the current pointee is retained and then released at the end of the current full-expression. This must execute atomically with respect to assignments and to the final release of the pointee.
> - For all other objects, the lvalue is loaded with primitive semantics.

It does not say why, but think of what happens if the object you got from __weak variable dies before you even started using it. The purpose of weak pointer is to make sure you have either `nil` or a valid object with well-known lifetime, that is why reading its value implies retaining the pointee (and then property's getter returns it autoreleased).

This is not unique to Obj-C, it's common idiom to all weak pointer implementations (both refcounted and garbage collected). Weak pointers can not give out pointer value directly, they have to create strong pointer to 'hold' object to make sure it won't die before caller has even started using it. In Obj-C, it's retain-autorelease; in C++, weak_ptr creates shared_ptr first, in garbage-collected environments, a strong reference is returned and the object's lifetime is prolonged silently.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have a doubt. correct me if i am wrong - The purpose of using a weak property is to ensure that the lifetime is not increased, just to use it as long as owner doesn't destroy it. Wouldn't it be against the purpose of using weak pointer if the lifetime was to be increased ?

Comment: @user1046037 I have updated my answer with a link to ARC specs that explicitly documents this behavior.

Comment: @user1046037 `weak` on a property is just an instruction for `@synthesize`. The behavior you're observing is due to `__weak` reading semantics: you can not convert weak to `unsafe_unretained` pointer to an object because it's lifetime can end at any moment, you have to retain the object before using it.

Comment: I feel [bar doSomethingThatDestroysFoo] can't destroy the instance that fooPtr is pointing to unless all the owners including fooPtr goes out of scope.

Comment: @user1046037 maybe that isn't a good example. We can say, an object returned by a method (getter) must have it's lifetime extended at least until the end of the current scope, and for weak pointers it would not be true without retaining them first.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! for patiently explaining it. You are correct, looks like i have a bit of reading to do. I will come back if i have any doubts on this. Thanks again !!

Answer (score 0):

Getter for x1 looks like:

```
function -[B xa1] {
    var_8 = rdi;
    var_0 = rsi;
    rdi = objc_loadWeakRetained(var_8 + *_OBJC_IVAR_$_B.xa1);
    rax = [rdi autorelease];
    return rax;
}
```

So when you get property in

```
A* a3 = b1.xa1;
```

a1 == b1.xa1 get autorelease call and retained by autoreleasepool